# How to make a space when concatenating strings

Tags: javascript

I have written some code that works fine but I am trying to make a space between the strings.

The code I have is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Concatenating Strings </title>
</head>
<body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
var greetingString = "Hello";
var myName = prompt ("Please enter your name","");
var concatString;
document.write(greetingString + "" + myName + "<br>");
concatString = greetingString + "" + myName;
document.write(concatString);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

At the moment the script shows HelloMichael, I am wanting it to show Hello Michael. Can someone please advise me on how I can do that?

Comment: If you want a space between the strings, concatenate them with a space.

Comment: oh c'mon... talk about low value questions :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert a space character, simply insert a space character.  For example:

```
greetingString + " " + myName
```

There's no space in your current output, because `""` doesn't have a space in it.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly now, something so simple too

Answer (score 2):

put a space between hello and michael like this:

```
concatString = greetingString + " " + myName; //notice the space in the string
```

Comment: Yes, I had put commas in instead. I'm relatively new to javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
concatString = greetingString + " " + myName;
```

Simply change your "" to " ", the second has a space in it.

Comment: While this is technically the solution to the OPs issue, it helps the OP (and indeed other users of StackOverflow) if you add an explanation along with your answer so that they can learn from the answer.  Just a thought as we are all learning here..